# Is it possible to make an Android App to CURTIN any website like GMAIL or FB

Tags: android

Is it possible ? Load any website in background (like Gmail/FB) and get inflated my App's widgets (like Username,Password) and when user gets Log-in , again my app get inflated.

In short, i want to make an App will be used as "Sandwich" between end-user and website. To achieve more user friendly environment and way to access the website. Because App will be used among non techno-savy peoples, So i want to present i their own way. Please help.

Comment: it will be easier to save the website bookmark to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WebView and enable caching on it.

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8); 
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(Context.getCacheDir()​);  
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true); 
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```